# Angular routing with modules - Not showing content for routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've been struggling with this annoying issue for a few days now and simply can't figure it out. Hoping someone can pick up my mistake as I am sure its something small.

Content for my routes in one of my modules are not showing, and are acting weird. When the route is `/dashboard` the dashboard components successfully shows, however when I navigate to another route like `/dashboard/status` the same content displays and the status component is not shown. If I change the route to just `/status` then the status component content shows, but it removes all of the dashboard layout components like the sidebar, navbar, etc.

Below is my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { layoutRoutes } from './modules/landing-layout/landing-layout-routing.module';

import { AccountDetailResolve } from './services/account/account-detail.resolve.service';
import { LandingLayoutComponent } from './modules/landing-layout/landing-layout.component';
import { DashboardLayoutComponent } from './modules/dashboard-layout/dashboard-layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LandingLayoutComponent,
        children: layoutRoutes
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboard-layout/dashboard-layout.module')
            .then(m => m.DashboardLayoutModule),
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [
        AccountDetailResolve
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is my `dashboard-layout-routing.module.ts`. As seen below, there are two types of dashboards. One for administrators, and one for customers. Each use their own outlet in the `dashboard-layout.component.html`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { adminRoutes } from '../admin/admin-routing.module';
import { AdminComponent } from '../admin/admin.component';
import { customerRoutes } from '../customer/customer-routing.module';
import { CustomerComponent } from '../customer/customer.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AdminComponent,
        outlet: 'admin',
        children: adminRoutes
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: CustomerComponent,
        outlet: 'customer',
        children: customerRoutes
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardLayoutRoutingModule { }
```

And finally this is my `customer-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AccountStatusComponent } from './components/account-status/account-status.component';
import { CustomerIndexComponent } from './components/index/customer-index/customer-index.component';

export const customerRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: CustomerIndexComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'status',
        component: AccountStatusComponent, 
    },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(customerRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CustomerRoutingModule { }
```

So basically, app goes to dashboard-layout and then to customer. As previously mentioned the blank path `path: ''` is working and showing the dashboard correctly, but when changing to the status, it remains on the dashboard, even though the url changes to `/dasboard/status`

I hope this is enough information to assist. Please advise if you need more.

**EDIT**

[Here's a simple StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fsozz4?) of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. So it seems my "named" router-outlets were causing the issues. So I ended up having to have a single router-outlet and switch between the modules on the dashboard-layout-routing.module.ts as shown below:

**Instead of in dashboard-layout.component.html**

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="systemAdmin" name="admin"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet *ngIf="!systemAdmin" name="customer"></router-outlet>
```

**I added this to dashboard-layout-routing.module.ts**

```
function routesFactory() {
    let isAdmin: boolean = true; //TODO:: Get from service
    return [
        {
            path: '',
            component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
            loadChildren: () => {
                return isAdmin ? 
                    import('../admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule) :
                    import('../customer/customer.module').then(m => m.CustomerModule);
        }
    }]
}
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild([])],
    providers: [{
        provide: ROUTES,
        useFactory: routesFactory,
        multi: true,
        deps: []
    }],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

It's now working as expected